# How to use API data in JSX after componentDidMount method, React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm making a basic bitcoin meter web-app which shows the rate of bitcoin. I'm making an API call in componentDidMount() method and getting the data successfully. But when I'm using it in JSX, it is throwing an error **this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi is undefined**

here's my `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ValueOfBitcoin: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => {
        var valueofbitcoin = response.data;
        console.log(valueofbitcoin);
        this.setState({ValueOfBitcoin: valueofbitcoin})
        console.log(this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi.USD.rate);
      })
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.ValueOfBitcoin);

    return (
      <div className="App">
            <h1>Bitcoin meter</h1>
            <div>
              <h2>Eur</h2><p>{this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi.EUR.rate}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>GBP</h2><p>{this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi.GBP.rate}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>USD</h2><p>{this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi.USD.rate}</p>
            </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

bpi is an object inside the main object I'm getting from API call. in bpi I've EUR, GBP & USD objects which have rate key.

Also this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi.USD.rate in componenetDidMount() is logging out successfully. But when I'm using this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi.USD.rate it is throwing **this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi is undefined**

Can anyone help?

Comment: your problem resolved. check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58668937/6544460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({valueofbitcoin: response.data})
      })
  }

  render(){
   const {valueofbitcoin} = this.state;
   let eurRate = valueofbitcoin ? valueofbitcoin.bpi.EUR.rate: ''
   let gbpRate = valueofbitcoin ? valueofbitcoin.bpi.GBP.rate: ''
   let usdRate = valueofbitcoin ? valueofbitcoin.bpi.USD.rate: ''
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Bitcoin meter</h1>
        <div>
          <h2>Eur</h2><p>{eurRate}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>GBP</h2><p>{gbpRate}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>USD</h2><p>{usdRate}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Typo here, you're using `ValueOfBitcoin` in some places and `valueofbitcoin` in others

Comment: It is not printing out the values, I found it is assigning empty string ' ' to the variables. And when I'm not using the ternary operator and directly assigning the values, I'm getting the same error that `this.state.ValueOfBitcoin.bpi` is undefined. So the question remains same.

Comment: @PrateekGautam use this code and check it's working properly. and when you are using directly this.state.valueodbitcoin it becomes undefined because it's initial value that's why you need to use ternary condition so when it gets value then only print.

Comment: Thanks, the code worked. But can you please explain what you did in the 15th line of your code is it destructuring of object? Also why wouldn't it worked when we declare a valueofbitcoin blank object in this.state method of constructor?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({valueofbitcoin: response.data})
      }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
          // that falls out of the range of 2xx
          console.log(error.response.data);
        } else if (error.request) {
          // The request was made but no response was received
          // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
          // http.ClientRequest in node.js
          console.log(error.request);
        } else {
          // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
          console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        console.log(error.config);
      });
  }

  render(){
   const {valueofbitcoin} = this.state;
   let eurRate = !!valueofbitcoin ? valueofbitcoin.bpi.EUR.rate: ''
   let gbpRate = !!valueofbitcoin ? valueofbitcoin.bpi.GBP.rate: ''
   let usdRate = !!valueofbitcoin ? valueofbitcoin.bpi.USD.rate: ''
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Bitcoin meter</h1>
        <div>
          <h2>Eur</h2><p>{eurRate}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>GBP</h2><p>{gbpRate}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>USD</h2><p>{usdRate}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

The !! checks if the response is null or undefined and also you should tackle the validations in the API call like this.